# Scope of variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

I'm having trouble understanding the scope of 'this' in this scenario. I'm able to call each one of these functions like: this.startTracking(); from within the time tracker switch object. However, when I try to execute the code: Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.stopTracking(); It loses all scope of variables and my GET request becomes undefined. How can I fire off stopTracking() onbeforeunload?

```
    Drupal.behaviors.dynamicTimeTracker = function (context) {
  $('form.node-time-tracker', context).each(function () {
    new Drupal.timeTracker(this);
  });
};

/**
 * A time tracker switch object
 */
Drupal.timeTracker = function (form) {
  var tracker = this;
  this.form = form;
  this.nid = $('#'+ form.id +' input[name="nid"]').attr('value');
  this.uid = $('#'+ form.id +' input[name="uid"]').attr('value');
  this.button = $('#'+ form.id +' input[type="submit"]');
  this.url = Drupal.settings.time_tracker.url + '/' + this.nid + '/' + this.uid;
  this.counter = $('#'+ form.id +' .counter');

  this.initialize(); // TODO: make sure this function is called regularly to make sure trackers are in synch
  this.startTracking();
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.stopTracking(); // need help here
  });
};

/**
 * Initialize the time tracker
 */
Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.initialize = function () {
  var tracker = this;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: tracker.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (status) {
      $(tracker.counter).countdown({compact:true, since:-status['time']}).countdown('resume');

      if (status['status'] == 'ongoing') {
        $(tracker.button).toggle(
          function() {
            tracker.stopTracking();
            return false;
          },
          function() {
            tracker.startTracking();
            return false;
          }
        );
        $(tracker.counter).countdown('resume');
        $(tracker.button).val(Drupal.t('Stop'));
        $(tracker.form).removeClass('node-time-tracker-start').addClass('node-time-tracker-stop');
      }
      else {
        $(tracker.button).toggle(
          function() {
            tracker.startTracking();
            return false;
          },
          function() {
            tracker.stopTracking();
            return false;
          }
        );
        $(tracker.counter).countdown('pause');
        $(tracker.button).val(Drupal.t('Start'));
        $(tracker.form).removeClass('node-time-tracker-stop').addClass('node-time-tracker-start');
      } 
    },
    error: function (xmlhttp) {
      alert(Drupal.ahahError(xmlhttp, tracker.startURL));
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Starts time tracking
 */
Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.startTracking = function () {
  var tracker = this;

  // Ajax GET request for starting time tracker
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: tracker.url + '/start',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (status) {
      $(tracker.counter).countdown('change', {since: -status['time']}).countdown('resume');
      $(tracker.button).val(Drupal.t('Stop'));
      $(tracker.form).removeClass('node-time-tracker-start').addClass('node-time-tracker-stop');
    },
    error: function (xmlhttp) {
      alert(Drupal.ahahError(xmlhttp, tracker.startURL));
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Stops time tracking
 */
Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.stopTracking = function () {
  var tracker = this;

  // Ajax GET request for stopping time tracker
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: tracker.url + '/stop',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (status) {
      $(tracker.counter).countdown('change', {since: -status['time']}).countdown('pause');
      $(tracker.button).val(Drupal.t('Start'));
      $(tracker.form).removeClass('node-time-tracker-stop').addClass('node-time-tracker-start');
    },
    error: function (xmlhttp) {
      alert(Drupal.ahahError(xmlhttp, tracker.startURL));
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just take out a little snippet:

```
this.startTracking();
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  // this is defined by the above function definition
  tracker.stopTracking();
});
```

Your problem is, that when you create the bind function, `this` inside it, will refer to `$(window)`, so you need to create a copy of this, to be able to reference it inside this new function.

Answer (score 0):

googletorp's answer should work, but just a quick note:

I believe the issue you're having is because you're trying to call:

```
Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.stopTracking();
```

Instead, I think it should it be:

```
Drupal.timeTracker.stopTracking();
```

I don't believe you're supposed to call functions on the prototype, but rather on the object whose prototype you've modified.

Comment: I did try this, and Firebug told me that my function was undefined

Comment: Interesting...I suppose I have more to learn about JS prototypes.

Comment: You don't inherit from the prototype until you instantiate the object (ie. you'd need to create an instance of `Drupal.timeTracker` to be able to use `stopTracking` without going through the prototype object)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new Drupal.timeTracker(this)`, it creates a new object. That object inherits from `Drupal.timeTracker.prototype`. Inside the methods of that object, `this` is set to the object itself. `Drupal.timeTracker.prototype` is not the object, but merely a template from which new instances of the object may be formed; Like a cookie-cutter, it's not very good to eat. Most importantly, none of the inner state of your actual timer lives there.

When you call `Drupal.timeTracker.prototype.stopTracking`, it's being called on the template, not the real object. If you call `tracker.stopTracking()`, you'll be okay. You can't call `this.stopTracking()`, because when you want to call `stopTracking`, you're in the event handler for `onbeforeunload`, so your `this` will be the `window` object.